# Replacing row data in column

Tags: r, replace

The data set i am using treat missing value as -99 and now I need to replace all these -99 to the number in same row but different column.

Here is the example

```
V1   V2    V3  V4       V5            V6        V7
1   1958    3 1958.208 315.71       315.71    314.62    -1
2   1958    4 1958.292 317.45       317.45    315.29    -1
3   1958    5 1958.375 317.50       317.50    314.71    -1
4   1958    6 1958.458 **-99.99**   *317.10*  314.85    -1
```

I want to replace (V5, 4) with (V6, 4).

There are several missing data in V5 and we want to replace with the same row in V6.

How to achieve this?

Comment: You can specify `na.string = -99` when you read the data in using `read.table()` and that will make `R recognize them as a missing value

Comment: Thanks but i want to replace by 317.10 the same row in column V6. Do you now how to replace that?

Answer (score 2):

It would be more sensible to specify the `NA` values when you read in your data.

You can do this by specifying the `na.string`  argument in `read.table()` (or some variant of such).

With your specific data, it is unclear whether you have a defined scheme (as in always replace with the value in the next column), but for replacing 'missing' values in column `V5` with their respective values in `V6` and assuming your data is called `DF`

```
 DF <- within(DF, V5 <- replace(V5, V5 == -99.99, V6[V5== -99.99])
```

would work.

If you have correctly specified the -99.99 as missing values (NA) then

```
DF <- within(DF, V5 <- replace(V5, is.na(V5), V6[is.na(V5)])
```

Comment: Using "==" with non-integer values is rather risky.

Comment: True. If the op reads the missing values correctly, it would avoided.